# Does invokeAny cancel all the threads in a Thread pool or only callables?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I'm creating a fixed size `ExecutorService`, which is going to be accessed from multiple threads.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
```

Then I'm calling `invokeAny` from two different threads using the same `ExecutorService`.

```
executorService.invokeAny(listCallables);
```

So there is a possibility that in the thread pool there can be multiple tasks called from different threads.

As per the [invokeAny](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny(java.util.Collection)) documentation:

> Upon normal or exceptional return, tasks that have not completed are cancelled.

My question is, upon successful return of `invokeAny`, will it cancel all the threads which are in the thread pool or will it cancel only the tasks which are called in separate threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `invokeAny` implementation in Java Sources:

```
try {
    ....
} finally {
    for (Future<T> f : futures)
        f.cancel(true);
}
```

This means `invokeAny` cancels only the callable-s which has been submitted to it.

Answer (score 2):

Upon normal return of `invokeAny`, the threadpool will cancel all uncompleted tasks. You can refer to my example:

```
package com.pechen;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SleepSecondsCallable implements Callable<String> {
    private String name;

    private int seconds;

    public SleepSecondsCallable(String name, int seconds) {
        this.name = name;
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    public String call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(name + ",begin to execute");

        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(seconds);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(name + " was disturbed during sleeping.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return name + ",fails to execute";
        }

        return name + ",success to execute";
    }

}
```

The main class:

```
package com.pechen;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);  

            List<Callable<String>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<String>>();  

            tasks.add(new SleepSecondsCallable("t1", 2));  
            tasks.add(new SleepSecondsCallable("t2", 1));  

            String result = executorService.invokeAny(tasks);  
            System.out.println(result);  
            executorService.shutdown();  

    }

}
```

The output:

```
t1,begin to execute
t2,begin to execute
t2,success to execute
t1 was disturbed during sleeping.
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.sleep(Unknown Source)
    at com.pechen.SleepSecondsCallable.call(SleepSecondsCallable.java:20)
    at com.pechen.SleepSecondsCallable.call(SleepSecondsCallable.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

You can see, specify thread `t2` to sleep for 1 second and `t1` for 2. When `t2` successfully returns, theadpool interupts the execution of `t1`.

Comment: Agreed. If you try to interrupt a thread which is still _sleeping_, you'll get `java.lang.InterruptedException`. But in my scenario consider the thread pool contains three tasks which has been called from different threads. In your example consider you're calling one more `executorService.invokeAny(tasks);`, but from completely different thread.

Comment: They are in different threads too but are the same task. You can create your own tasks and throw them into the thread pool to have a try.